# Can flexbox force an SVG element to resize?

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

**Context**: I would like to my blog a list of projects (as logos with links) that I relied on to build it as an acknowledgment. They will be displayed on a sidebar.

**Problem**: The SVG logos have each a different initial (default) size. I would like them to expand horizontally preserving the ratio.

I simulated this through the code below, where the `<svg>` represents a file with a logo

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 1px;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.logo {}
```

```html
<div class="column">

  <div class="logo">
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
    <svg width="25" height="50">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </div>

</div>
```

I was hoping that `flex-grow: 1;` would expand the rectangles, to end up with the two of the same width, and the red one twice the height of the green one.

**Is it possible for `flex` to force a resizing of an SVG element?**

Comment: Use a viewBox attribute instead of width and height for the svg element. For example use ` viewBox="0 0 50 50"` instead of `width="50" height="50"`

Answer (score 1):

Like below maybe:

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 1px;
  gap: 10px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">

  <div class="logo">
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
    <svg width="25" height="50">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the width and the height attributes on `<svg>` with a viewBox attribute, the SVG will take up 100% of the available space.

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 1px;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.logo {}
```

```html
<div class="column">

  <div class="logo">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 25 50">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is a very good idea - unfortunately I do not control the SVG file (well, I could but I would like to avoid modifying the logo definition)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the SVG files as src in an `<img>` and set that to 100% in width.

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 1px;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">

  <div class="logo">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1MCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1MCI+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgZmlsbD0iZ3JlZW4iIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo="/>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNSIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1MCI+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgZmlsbD0icmVkIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4K"/>
  </div>

</div>
```